# Remove 'Finish Later' button from DocuSign powerform

Tags: docusignapi, powerform

I am using Powerform for the digital signature. I have kept the return URL in the Destination URL section. But for the Finish later URL, is there any way to identify the user who kept the form for 'Finish later'? Eg: Adding an extra parameter, email of the user filling the form. So that, the user details can be updated in my DB system one the user redirect back to my website. Or,  Is it possible to remove the 'Finish Later' button from the power form?
Thanks in Advance.

In my DocuSign account, I have added custom 'Merge Fields', 'sec1_email', and dragged and kept it in the email section in the PDF. In the destination URL I have added, ''http://localhost/proj/testform/?docustatus=completed&email=[[sec1_email]]' expecting, the sec1_email will replace the email id entered by the user in the form. Then once the user submit the form and the return URL became, 'http://localhost/proj/testform/?docustatus=completed&email=[[sec1_email]]'. The URL returned the same string instead of the dynamic value email. How can I replace the custom field value 'sec1_email' which was entered in the form by the user in the URL? (In template settings, When I add the merge filed, those added fields appear in the custom fields.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to pass a unique variable in and out of the PowerForm via URL parameters. https://support.docusign.com/en/guides/ndse-user-guide-populate-custom-document-fields-in-a-web-powerform

Essentially you would want to create a custom field on the envelope, then pass in a unique identifier via the PowerForm URL. When the PowerForm completes or someone hits Finish Later, it goes to your designated landing page. These landing pages can also have parameters passed back through them. Essentially it would go from Finish Later > http://www.yourdomain.com/landingpage?customerUserId=uniqueIdentifier.
https://support.docusign.com/en/articles/How-do-I-specify-a-URL-to-redirect-to-when-a-Powerform-is-completed

Comment: Thanks for the response. Can you please check the updated Question? I have tried the way mentioned in the URL but unfortunately not worked.

Comment: Hi Adam,
Apologies, allow me to clarify. There are two different types of custom fields -- one type that you drag over from the tagger, and another you would normally see on the recipients and routing screen. The latter is where these custom fields need to be set. First glance your URL parameters look just fine.

Comment: Hi Matt, I have added Custom filed under 'Signing and sending' > 'Document custom fields'. Stiil in the return url after redirection,   http://localhost/proj/test-form/?docustatus=completed&email=[[sec1_email]]&env=3abbfe58-7457-4544-a3fd-77c144bc4bc0&pf=36c0bd2d-822e-430e-84c5-7e20324bb80b&r=c5fdcf56-4c94-4c6b-87b8-0207173d423c. The [[sec1_email]] is not replaced with the email id. Thanks.

Comment: You'll need to add an Envelope Custom Field. For example, the field I added for my test was "Custom_Text". In the PowerForm URL, I added ?EnvelopeField_Custom_Text=SampleValue to the PowerForm URL. In my In-session landing pages (Settings -> Signing Settings > In-session landing pages), I set the complete URL to https://www.example.com/landingpage?CustomValue=[[Custom_Text]]. After completing the PowerForm, I was directed to https://www.example.com/landingpage?CustomValue=SampleValue.

Comment: Hi Matt, What is the SampleValue in the example you have mentioned? '?EnvelopeField_Custom_Text=SampleValue'. How can we make this SampleValue to a dynamic value such as the email submitted by the user? (email is a field in powerform I have added) Public user has entered the email id in the powerform eg:abc@abc.com I need to get the 'emaiid' in the return URL ie,  example.com/landingpage?email=abc@abc.com. Thank you.

Comment: SampleValue is a generic value I fed in via an Envelope Custom Field. You can see your available mergfields if you goto Settings > Branding > Edit Brand > Destination URLs, when you select a text field a new dropdown should appear with a list of available mergefields. It looks like the one you may be looking for could be as simple as [[RecipientEmail]] -- which should send the end-user to their landing page with the email attached as a URL parameter.

Comment: Hi Matt, I have got the added filed in the merge field. I have added the merged field also. Now the URL I have added in the destination URL for 'signing completed' is, http://localhost/proj/test/?docustatus=completed&customfield=[[RecipientEmail]]. Once the user has submitted the form it redirected my website. But the URL is not replacing with the email id. How it is possible to replace the email id in the  powerform with the [[RecipientEmail]] ? Bit confused. Thank you so much for your time.

Comment: Thank you so much, Matt. The issue has been fixed.  I have added the Envelop field, 'recipientMail'. and in the destination URL, added the custom envelope field.  'email=[[recipientMail]]'. In the form passed 'EnvelopeField_recipientMail'. Now the return URL shows the custom email id. Thanks Again.